# How can I create a select with all specific rows of an user?

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I trying to make a select that should be post and contain all the votacoes from an user

```
  <select name="votacao" size="1">

     <option>

       <?php
         $sql = "SELECT nome_votacao FROM votacoes WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['id']";
         $rs = mysql_query($sql);                       
         while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)) 
             echo $row['nome_votacao'];             
       ?>   

    </option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<option>` needs to be in your loop:

```
<select name="votacao" size="1">


       <?php
         $sql = "SELECT nome_votacao FROM votacoes WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['id']";
         $rs = mysql_query($sql);                       
         while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)) {
             echo sprintf("<option>%s</option>\n", $row['nome_votacao']);  
         }      
       ?>   



</select>
```

You probably need to also add a unique ID as the `value` attribute for each `<option>` for this to be truly useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="votacao" size="1"> 
       <?php 
         $sql = "SELECT nome_votacao FROM votacoes WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['id']"; 
         $rs = mysql_query($sql);                        
         while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs))  
             echo "<option>".$row['nome_votacao']."</option>";              
       ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<select name="votacao" size="1">

     <option>

       <?php
         $sql = "SELECT nome_votacao FROM votacoes WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['id']";
         $rs = mysql_query($sql);     
          foreach ($rs as $row)        
          { ?>

           <option> <?php echo $row['nome_votacao']; ?> </option>
       <? } ?>   

    </option>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /var/www/jquery/painel.php on line 48